# wp_query between to date in european format

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to query some posts between 2 dates, look like it's not working because my posts are not int YYYYMMDD format but in european format DD.MM.YYYY

```
  $args = array(
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'meta_key' => 'usp-custom-rdvp_date_event_start',
  "order" => "ASC",
  'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key'     => 'usp-custom-rdvp_date_event_start',
        'value'   => array( $fromDate, $toDate ),
        'type'    => 'DATE',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
      ),
  ),
);
```

Did you have a hack to query between 2 European date?

PS. I can't change the date format

Comment: No, if date format in usp-custom-rdvp_date_event_start and  $fromDate $toDate is YYYYMMDD this operation is working.

If date format is something else (for me : DD.MM.YYYY) this query is not working. I can't change the value stored in DB usp-custom-rdvp_date_event_start, so the question is :

Comment: how to query with wp_query with special dateformat. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change the date format with some array manipulation:

```
$mydate = 'DD.MM.YYYY';
echo implode( '', array_reverse( explode('.', $mydate) ) ); # Output: YYYYMMDD
```

You may also find a better way using the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

```
$date_str = '02.04.2016';
$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'd.m.Y', $date_str );
echo $myDateTime->format( 'Ymd' ); # Output: 20160402
```

Comment: Hello,
Sorry I think there is a misunderstanding. I can't change the value of "usp-custom-rdvp_date_event_start", it's stored this was in the DB this way by another soft. My problem is not to display the date format in another way, my problem is to query post with "wp_query"

Comment: Once you know how to change the format you can apply that to `$fromDate` and `$toDate`.

Comment: Sorry again no. 
usp-custom-rdvp_date_event_start  and $fromDate and $toDate 
are ALL in the same date format -> DD.MM.YYYY
It's just that WP_query look like he don't understand that date format 
 'type'    => 'DATE', or  'type'    => 'NUMERIC'

Comment: I found what is happening more exactly:

When I query between two dates and that all 3 dates are in the format DD.MM.YYYY, wp_query test only the “DD” part. So if I query between 23.12.2016 and 25.12.2016, I get all “23, 24 and 25” of every month and years. Probably the “.” is interpreted as a numeric value (event if I use compare => “date”). The query is interpreted the same was as if I was asking between numbers  23,122016 and 25,122016. that maybe also before I'm in 'meta_query'